# SFDX: Deploy Source to Org: Errors do not appear as Problems in Visual Studio Code

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode

How do I get the errors returned from command:

```
 SFDX: Deploy Source to Org
```

To appear in the Visual Studio Code Problem Window?

As this would allow us to click on the error and be taken directly to the problem line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently an item in the [roadmap](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/588) of the Salesforce Extensions for VS Code.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea when it might arrive? :)

Comment: It’s currently set for Winter ‘19, but you should keep looking at the issue in GitHub to see if there is any change in the ETA.